# First SKAction in chain of animations not working properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make 2 actions in sequence, but I want to change a variable in between the actions. For some reason, the first animation in the chain never works. What it does do is freeze the code for a long while (longer than the animation is supposed to run for), and then skips to the next animation without having played the first one.

I tried taking out the first action, and then the second action (now the first) didn't run, in the same way as the other didn't.
I also tried changing what the animation does, and same results.
I know of the sequence function, but as I want to change a variable in between the animations, I don't use it.

I set the SKActions like this:

```
fadeIn  = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1.0, duration: 0.5)
fadeOut = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.0, duration: 0.5)
```

and then run them like this:

```
self.textSKNode.run(self.fadeOut) { // this action does not run
    self.label.text = text // changing the variable
    self.textSKNode.run(self.fadeIn) { // this action runs perfectly
        // then I run some code here of outside objects
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `SKAction.run` to change the label and then create a sequence as shown below. I slowed it down a bit just to see the effect more clearly.

```
let fadeInAction  = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1.0, duration: 2.0)
let fadeOutAction = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.0, duration: 2.0)
let changeLabelTextAction = SKAction.run({
    textSKNode.text = "New Text"
})

let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOutAction, changeLabelTextAction, fadeInAction])
textSKNode.run(actionSequence)
```

Comment: now none of the fades work for me...
I've tried to add a .wait before the sequence, chained as well, then the fades work, but still take a lot longer than it's supposed to.
it's like this now: 

let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, changeLabelText, fadeIn])
self.textSKNode.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1)) {
      self.textSKNode.run(actionSequence) {
           self.masterManager.canClick = true
       }
}

Comment: I have no idea why waitForDuration would have any effect on the animation. Except to delay it. When I get stuck, I break the problem down into very small and simple pieces. Start with the Hello World label from the sample app. Add an animation sequence to it. When that's working, add a closure. Build it back up into what you want. Then go back to your app and you should be able to see why it's not working.